# Does BigQuery support regular expressions flags?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I want to do a case insensitive REGEX_MATCH and I'm not sure if I can use flags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

BigQuery uses re2 for regular expressions, and re2 does support flags.

For example, to do a case insensitive match:

```
SELECT REGEXP_MATCH('TomatoPotato', r'TOpo')
false

SELECT REGEXP_MATCH('TomatoPotato', r'(?:TOpo)')
false

SELECT REGEXP_MATCH('TomatoPotato', r'(?i:TOpo)')
true
```

Comment: What is the first `r` in the last argument? Sorry I googled it but cannot find anything about it

Comment: "String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences. "